# Looking for examples of valid Objective-C ARC code that crashes at runtime

Tags: objective-c, llvm, automatic-ref-counting

To better understand ARC I'm looking for example code that compiles perfectly with ARC enabled , but crashes at runtime. Ie the common pitfalls that may be overlooked and can cause you a debugging nightmare if you've never encountered that issue before.

Real life examples tuned down to the minimum code that reproduces the issues would be very helpful. In particular if the ARC code is interfacing with C or C++ code.

Comment: It is, a rather good one I think

Comment: It is too vague.  There are a myriad of examples that could be done with overly liberal casting (i.e. `[(_bridge id)0x42 hash];`.  There are likely some patterns that could crash w/o evil casting, but those are just bugs. Ultimately, though, it isn't clear what the real question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick example of the many I was thinking along the same lines as bbum.

Casting from CF... to NS... confuses ARC if done incorrectly for example:

```
CFArrayRef *supportedInterfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
NSArray *interfaceNames = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)supportedInterfaces;
CFRelease(supportedInterfaces);
```

Would over-release supportedInterfaces since __bridge_transfer retains the NSArray while releasing the CFArrayRef. In this case either don't use the CFRelease() or use plain __bridge.